# VBA If exists copy to the next row in antoher sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to sort in another sheet values that I have received and I wrote:

```
Sub copy_to_report()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long

For i = 2 To 500
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 24) <> "" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 25) <> "" Then
        Lastrow = Sheets("report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("report").Cells(Lastrow, 3) = Cells(i, 24)
        Sheets("report").Cells(Lastrow, 4) = Cells(i, 25)
    End If
Next     
End Sub
```

However it doesn't work. I'd like to check if in a row there is something in 25 and 24 and if yes, copy it from sheet1 to my "report"sheet. Could you please help me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your `Cells` are not qualified with the relevant `Worksheet`, the same goes for `Lastrow`.

You may try something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_to_report()

Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ShtReport As Worksheet

Set ShtReport = Worksheets("report")

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To 500
        If .Cells(i, 24) <> "" And .Cells(i, 25) <> "" Then
            'Lastrow = ShtReport.Cells(ShtReport.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ' maybe it's better to check for last row in Column "C"
            Lastrow = ShtReport.Cells(ShtReport.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            ShtReport.Cells(Lastrow, 3) = .Cells(i, 24)
            ShtReport.Cells(Lastrow, 4) = .Cells(i, 25)
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```